# Website stuck in redirect loop when setting up website through Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, nginx

I am actually a bit stuck with this redirect loop, i have created a bash script for automation of creating nGinx blocks and it works pretty well, but the website gets stuck in redirect loop, also the Server IP gets stuck in redirect loop.
Bash Script Code is,

```
echo "Please Enter your Domain Name"
read domain
sudo mkdir /var/www/$domain ;
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/$domain ;
echo "server {
   listen 80;
   server_name $domain www.$domain;
   root /var/www/$domain;

   index index.html index.htm index.php;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

   location ~ /\.ht {
       deny all;
   }

}" > /etc/nginx/sites-available/$domain ;
echo "Domain Name $domain is added, Please make sure your Domain is pointing to this Server"
sleep 2
echo "configuring nGinx for the mentioned website, Please allow few minutes!"
sleep 2
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/$domain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ ;
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ;

echo "configuration files are created successfully, reloading nGinx web server to apply changes!"
sleep 2
sudo nginx -t ;
sleep 2
sudo systemctl reload nginx ;
```

Interestingly when setting up blocks manually through the commands which i used in bash script, Domain works well but when setting up through bash script it gets stuck in redirect loop.
I am new to bash scripting and trying to learn and understand stuff.
If anyone can guide me in right direction, i would be really grateful.

Thank you,

Comment: Compare your bash generated domain file that fails to your manually generated domain file that works. You'll see that `$uri` is missing from the bash generated one because it's interpreted as a shell variable. ([ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) warns about this and other common errors)

Comment: Ahh got that, thank you, 
I guess i was too tired to pick that. 

is there anyway to make sure to $uri $uri/ inserts when running bash script?

Comment: Yes, @AhtshamJutt.  Look up "quoting" in the Bash manual.

Comment: Escape it with `echo " ...  \$uri ..."`